# Feed a Python list to js to highlight sections in a custom seekbar for html page in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I currently have a Flask app in Python which displays a video. Below the video is a custom seekbar. This seekbar has a single highlighted section that I manually added into the js script (I have noted this section in the below code). I would like to:

- create more highlighted sections in the seekbar by feeding the values of a python list to the js code

Please see the below files

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    list_of_timestamps = [30, 50, 70, 90]
    duration_of_timestamps = [2, 5, 10, 40]
    return render_template('index.html', 
                           list_of_timestamps=list_of_timestamps, 
                           duration_of_timestamps=duration_of_timestamps)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

templates/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/style.css')}}">
    <title>Custom Video Player</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" controls width="800">
        <source src="{{url_for('static', filename='videos/1.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div id="custom-seekbar" onclick="seek(event)">
        <div id="highlight"></div>
        <div id="progress"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/custom.js')}}></script>
</body>
</html>
```

static/css/style.css:

```
#custom-seekbar {
    width: 800px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #ddd;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-inline-start: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#highlight {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    width: 0; /* will be set dynamically */
    left: 0; /* will be set dynamically */
    z-index:1; #keep the highlight above the progress*/
}

#progress {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(170, 166, 166, 0.5);
    width: 0;
    z-index:2; #keep the progress below the highlight */
}
```

static/js/custom.js:

```
const video = document.getElementById("video");
const customSeekbar = document.getElementById("custom-seekbar");
const highlight = document.getElementById("highlight");
const progress = document.getElementById("progress");

const highlightStart = 30; // this is the start point in seconds which I would like to somehow feed the python list list_of_timestamps to
const highlightDuration = 10; // This is where i would like duration_of_timestamps to go

video.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
    const highlightWidth = (highlightDuration / video.duration) * 100;
    const highlightPosition - (highlightStart / video.duration) * 100;
    highlight.style.width = highlightWidth + "%";
    highlight.style.left = highlightPosition + "%";
});

function seek(event) {
    const percent = event.offsetX / customSeekbar.offsetWidth;
    video.currentTime = percent * video.duration;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so hat have you tried? What part of this in particular is giving you trouble?

Comment: so im having trouble feeding a Python list through to the js script (as per question). Ive currently tried a static value which works (as per js script above). Im unsure how to feed the lists list_of_timestamps and duration_of_timestamps to the js script as im not very experienced with js

Comment: _"feeding a Python list through to the js script"_ - you should encode it as JSON, and then just populate a JS variable inside your template with that JSON, `var list_of_timestamps = THAT_JSON;`

Comment: And your JavaScript will obviously need modifications on a very basic level then already - because with just _one_ `<div id="highlight"></div>`, you will of course not be able to display _multiple_ such highlights. So instead of having that element in your HTML to begin with, you should create the needed number of elements dynamically - while you are looping over your data. (And use classes, where necessary - otherwise, you would have to add an index to your IDs or something like that, to keep them unique.)

Comment: I appreciate the replies so far but (and im not sure if youre meaning to) unfortunately its coming across a little passive aggressive. its not extremely helpful to say that it "obviously needs modifications". Yes, Thats why im here. Im not very experienced with js, as mentioned. "you should create the needed number of elements dynamically" again, im not very experienced with js so im not sure how I would do this.

Comment: Ok so you were doing it intentionally, im just looking for help, not to be berated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found an answer, posting for anyone stuck on similar:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/style.css')}}">
    <title>Custom Video Player</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" controls width="800">
        <source src="{{url_for('static', filename='videos/1.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div id="custom-seekbar" onclick="seek(event)"></div>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/custom.js')}}></script>
</body>
</html>
```

custom.js:

```
const video = document.getElementById("video");
const customSeekbar = document.getElementById("custom-seekbar");

const pDiv = document.createElement("div");
pDiv.id = "progress";
customSeekbar.appendChild(pDiv);

const highlightStart = [30, 50, 70, 90];
const highlightDuration = [2, 5, 10, 40];

video.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
    for(var i=0; i<highlightStart.length; i+=1) {
        const hDiv = document.createElement("div");
        hDiv.id = "highlight";
        customSeekbar.appendChild(hDiv);
        var highlightWidth = (highlightDuration / video.duration) * 100;
        var highlightPosition - (highlightStart / video.duration) * 100;
        highlight.style.width = highlightWidth + "%";
        highlight.style.left = highlightPosition + "%";
    };
});

function seek(event) {
    const percent = event.offsetX / customSeekbar.offsetWidth;
    video.currentTime = percent * video.duration;
}
```